# Get auto-asigned local IP address of TcpListener

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

Here's my code:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 0);
listener.Start();
var v = (IPEndPoint)listener.LocalEndpoint;
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_TcpListener__ctor_System_Net_IPAddress_System_Int32_)

> If you do not care which local address is assigned, specify
> IPAddress.Any for the localaddr parameter, and the underlying service
> provider will assign the most appropriate network address. ...If you
> use this approach, you can discover what local network address and
> port number has been assigned by using the LocalEndpoint property.

unfortunately, the address is always 0.0.0.0.

How do I discover the actual local ip address of the `TcpListener`?

**EDIT**

The code *does* work for the port. `v` does indeed have a *specific* port assigned to it.

Comment: That's not how listening works. Listening on `0.0.0.0` means any available listening interface. There is no specific address. In other words I think the docs are wrong IMHO

Comment: @Charlieface It's true that it's one of `any available listening interface`s. I doubt it listens on multiple ones if they are available. Just like it assigns _a specific port_ since I'm entering 0 for port - it doesn't listen on all ports.

Comment: Have a look at `netstat` and see if you can see a address or port

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks. But I need the app to do this. Whether it's on Windows, Android, iOS, or who knows what in the future. I need it to be able to inform others where it's listening, so that they can use a `TcpClient` to connect to it.

Comment: Do you have multiple network adapters (real or virtual) because if you don't it's obviously going to be the address of one that you have.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Since the app might be executed on many different hardware configurations not under the developers' control, I'd like to get the address the correct way (as in the docs (which seem to be wrong...)). Currently I'm doing what you're suggesting and just taking the first local ip address the device has. But that's not the robust way of doing this.

Comment: Well, I obviously don't know your use case/scenario, but in my case we frequently need to be able to specify a particular adapter to listen on because the computer is connected to multiple networks. There is no way for Windows to figure out on its own which adapter we want the application to listen on - it has to be specified in the call when the listener is created.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError So you agree with `Charlieface` that the docs are wrong?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I can't specify the adapter because I don't know anything about what's available. All I need is to have code that will listen _somewhere_ and then I need to get that address.

Comment: `IPAddress.Any` is a property that has the value `0.0.0.0`. All you are doing is setting and getting that property. It's working as intended. You have to wait for something to connect to your listener. Then you get the property of the `Socket` that tells you it's local address.

Comment: You mentioned in your edit that the listener gets created when you specify `IPAddress.Any, 0`. Can clients connect to the machine's main IP when you do that? - I must admit that I don't know the implications of the 0.0.0.0 address vs an actual IP - we've never used them though I usually do see several entries with that in response to e.g. `netstat -ano`.

Comment: A listener can have more than one client connection.  The best way of getting remote endpoints (the IP address) is to use an Ansync Listener and capture the socket from the client in the Accept method.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes, using the device's actual local ip address + the auto created port (included in `v` in the example above) they can create a TCP connection and send data to it.

Comment: @Andy I also set port 0 but get a different port. And there's no point in the address being 0.0.0.0 because potential clients need a specific address to connect to. They can't connect to "0.0.0.0" of course.

Comment: I would expect so - I meant when you use `IPAddress.Any`. To your last point to Andy, it's possible that clients can connect to the machine using its "real" IP when it says locally that it's listening on 0.0.0.0 - that's what I'm curious about.

Comment: @Andy Also, the docs I quoted clearly state that an address will be assigned and that I should be able to get it from the `TcpListener`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I guess I wasn't clear enough in my last comment to you. I _did_ mean that when I use `IPAddress.Any` in device A - the exact code in my question, I can then connect to the device running this code (device A), from device B, when device B creates a connection to device A's actual ip address.

Comment: I googled - apparently listening on 0.0.0.0 means listening on all adapters. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @jdweng That won't help since I need to know the local ip address (of device A) in order for another device (device B) to connect to it. There is no connection until I know the address (of device A).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError So the docs (in my question) are wrong?

Comment: The listener uses the IP address of the machine.  So you use folloiwng :                LocalHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                LocalHostIPEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(LocalHostName);
                LocalHostIP = LocalHostIPEntry.AddressList[1];

Comment: @BenVoigt It's worse than that. The text `you can discover what local network address and port number has been assigned by using the LocalEndpoint property.` has a link to [TcpListener.LocalEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.localendpoint?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @jdweng That's exactly what I'm doing now. But it's not robust. See [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703835/get-auto-asigned-local-ip-address-of-tcplistener#comment116170585_65703835).

Comment: The only issue is the index.  Most computers these days have IPV6 for index zero and index 1 as IPV4 .  To make robust you need to enumerate through the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In additional to everything which Andy said about LocalEndpoint having the local address for each incoming connection, which is correct, this statement in the documentation is flat out wrong:

> the underlying service provider will assign the most appropriate network address

Actually, `LocalEndpoint` will give you the address which the client sent the TCP SYN packet to.  It will be one of your network addresses, and it will often be the one that the local routing table would choose if initiating a connection to that client address without first binding the outgoing socket to a specific local address, but it doesn't have to be.

The client, not the TCP/IP stack, selects the IP address.

---

FWIW, that local address could end up being any one of the addresses you find through `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`.  It is not restricted to the ones you can see through `Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())`, although the addresses registered in DNS are the most likely to be useful on a larger network.  And the list of possible addresses can change, as a result of network connections making and breaking and also as a result of dynamically assigned address (DHCP) changes.

The `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange` class can be used to find out when the local address list is updated.

Comment: OK. If the docs are wrong they're wrong... I was relying on them.

Comment: @ispiro So after all was said and done, I was right what I said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703835/get-auto-asigned-local-ip-address-of-tcplistener#comment116168854_65703835) after all for calling out the docs for being wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In the docs for `IPAddress.Any`, it [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.any):

*The Socket.Bind method uses the Any field to indicate that a Socket instance must listen for client activity on all network interfaces.*

By simply creating a `TCPListener` with this property, you tell the framework that you don't care which interface it uses, just pick the best one *when something connects*, not before.

In order for the framework to pick the best one, it needs a client to connect to it. When something connects, it chooses the best one *for that instance* at *that time*.

The next client that connects may get the same interface, or, it could get a different one because you choose `IPAddress.Any`

You state it in your question:

*If you do not care which local address is assigned, specify IPAddress.Any for the localaddr parameter, and the underlying service provider will assign the most appropriate network address. ...If you use this approach, you can discover what local network address and port number has been assigned **by using the LocalEndpoint property**.*

**This is what you aren't understanding:**

The emphasis above talks about the `LocalEndpoint` of the `*Socket*` that is created from accepting the connection -- not the listening `TCPListener`.

The docs could be more clear on this point, sure -- but once you understand how listeners work, this should click.

Comment: You state `The emphasis above talks about the LocalEndpoint of the *Socket* that is created from accepting the connection -- not the listening TCPListener.` - but that's _not_ what the docs say. Follow the link to the documentation (in my question) and see that the text `LocalEndpoint` is actually a link to [TcpListener.LocalEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_TcpListener__ctor_System_Net_IPAddress_System_Int32_).

Comment: right -- because you could assign anything to that field, not just `IPAddress.Any`. You could explicitly assign an actual network interface address. MSDN docs are very open-ended and obligatory/generic. They are stating facts. You used `IPAddress.Any` is it's network interface -- so that's what it's reporting.

Comment: @Andy That doesn't follow, because you pass `0` for the port and the local TCP/IP stack (not the framework) does pick a specific port number which you can learn by inspecting the `LocalEndpoint` properly.

Comment: @Andy If you would just follow the link and read the official docs you would see you are wrong. The sentence there begins with `If you use this approach...` referring to using IPAddress.Any (and port 0).

Comment: @BenVoigt -- I am pretty sure setting 0 for port doesn't have the same semantics as setting `INADDR_ANY` for the IP address. In order for something to connect to your listener a port number *must be defined* otherwise, what is it going to connect to?

Comment: @Andy: Yes the semantics are different.  That's why you can't make universal statements like "It's reporting what you used"

Comment: @BenVoigt -- got it -- yeah i worded that wrong. Thanks